# lockless concurrent writing to a O_APPEND file

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am going to implement an append only database, capable of concurrent writing. As POSIX states, and according to my investigations, `write(2)` on a file opened with `O_APPEND` flag is guaranteed to write data at the end of the file without interleaving with the concurrent writing threads. But after writing a chunk of a data I need to tell at which offset the data has been written. Just getting current file size with stat or current write pointer with `lseek(2)` seems to be incorrect as it might race with the concurrent writers. Any thoughts on how to do that without locking?

Comment: I don't think such a design can work, simply because `write(2)` can write less data than requested. How do you plan to handle that case?

Comment: Well, write(2) can tell you how many data was actually written. Also I am going to preallocate desired amount of data with fallocate(2) prior to issuing write(2), but omitted that step for clarity.

Comment: Because `write()` and any operation that determines the current file offset are separate (non-atomic) operations, there isn't a reliable lock-free mechanism available in a multi-threaded program (or, indeed, with multi-processing).

Comment: `write()` can tell you how much you got written, so the question is how do you handle this being less than you expected?

Comment: In my case this is not a problem since it is allowed to leave invalid/unused chunks of data in the file. What I need from the writer process is to tell that the chunk has been written, it is of X size and it is at Y offset. Then I will add these parameters to the index (a B+Tree in another file). If the chunk was invalid, I simply do not add it to the index. Lately I can remove those garbage chunks either by completely rewriting the data file or remove garbage parts using `fallocate(2)` with `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` flag.

Comment: Also, as I said above, I am going to preallocate required space in the file by `fallocate`, so it is very unlikely that `write` will fail.

Comment: So far I plan to share a global write pointer which would be incremented by each write process. Seems to be the simplest, yet performant solution to reliably get the current offset in the file.